# Eloquent get ALL users, but order from related table first

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm building my very first Laravel project and I'm trying to get all users and sort them by the amount of products they have. This is my code:

I have User.php

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Product.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

UsersController.php

```
    public function index()
    {

        $user = User::select(DB::raw('users.*, count(*) as `products`'))
            ->join('products', 'users.id', '=', 'products.user_id')
            ->groupBy('user_id')
            ->orderBy('products', 'desc')
            ->get();

        return response($user, 200);

    }
```

This returns this JSON:

```
{
    id: 5,
    role: 1,
    state: 1,
    name: "Frida Greenfelder",
    email: "cummings.alfreda@example.org",
    email_verified_at: "2019-09-11 13:23:20",
    date_of_birth: "1981-01-28",
    created_at: "2019-09-11 13:23:20",
    updated_at: "2019-09-11 13:23:20",
    products: 8
},
```

This works, however, this only returns the users that have a product and them sorts them. What I'm trying to do is get ALL users and first sort them by the amount of products they have. Some users do not have products, which means that their user id is not inside of the products table. For users without a product, it should just return the user with product: 0.

How would I go about doing this?
I've had some trouble searching online for this exact problem/solution, hence this question.

Comment: replace JOIN with LEFT JOIN

Comment: try to replace  ->join('products', 'users.id', '=', 'products.user_id')
to ->with('products')

Comment: Try `$user = User::with('products')
            ->withCount('products')
            ->orderBy('products_count', 'desc')
            ->get();`

Comment: @theebigbang That get's me: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_id' in 'group statement' (SQL: select users.*, count(*) as `products` from `users` group by `user_id` order by `products` desc)

Comment: @ab_ This is what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Eloquent:

```php
public function index()
{ 

    $user = User::with('products')->withCount('products')->orderBy('products_count', 'desc')->get();

   return response($user, 200);
}
```